# Double integral in complex variables form.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Rewrite $\displaystyle \iint f(x,y) dx \, dy$ in complex variable form of $\displaystyle \iint g(z, \bar{z}) dz \, d\bar{z}$?

Where $z=x+iy$, $\bar{z}=x-iy$ and $x$ changes from $0$ to $a$ and $y$ changes from $0$ to $b$.